# Tricky LINQ function

Tags: linq-to-sql

In my application I have entities like User, Person and Group which are also of an IMember type (as they can be a members of some user group). There are also tables User, Person and Group in my MS SQL 2008 database which persist corresponding entity data.
I often need to get all these entities or entity collections as one collection - for example when I'm getting all members of some group or I'm searching members by their names or whatever. For this purpose i'd like to have ONE application method where all tables which correspond to IMember type are determined (in the future some tables may be added). This function should return all retrieved objects in one collection and i also want the function to accept some conditions to perform needed request for each table because I'll have a number of more specific functions calling the above. For example, if i wanna get all IMember's which names are "nick", the function should search for "nick" in User, Person and Group tables. What is the best way to pass such conditions and keep the final SQL query optimal?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd like to restate your problem the way I understand it.  You have some tables in a database like the following:

```
--SQL DDL
CREATE TABLE [User](
  Name varchar(25),
  Location varchar(50)
  --Other User specific columns like login, expireDate etc.
)

CREATE TABLE Person(
  Name varchar(25),
  Location varchar(50)
  --Other Person specific columns like Birthday etc.
)
```

The tables all have a *base* group of columns that represent a member.  In code, you have an `IMember` interface defined like so.  (Are you working in C# or VB?)

```
//C# code
interface IMember
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Location { get; set; }
}

'VB code
Interface IMember
    Property Name As String
    Property Location As String
End Interface
```

What you would like is to operate on all IMembers as a logically single collection.  More Information as to any restrictions or preferences you may have would be nice such as: is it feasible/ do you have access to change the layout of the database?  Can you add stored procedures to the database to facilitate the operations on the collection.  Is it just selecting Members that you need or do you need to be able to insert/update/delete members as well?  Is it OK to have to recompile your code with a minimal amount of changes when a new derived member table gets added to the DB. Also if you're going to be asking for a solution that may include code snippets, it's nice to know what .NET language you prefer if any.  Also "optimal" has many meanings for many people, simplest in terms of code? fastest? fewest round trips? is perfectly optimal truly a requirement or is there a "good enough"?

That said, here are some possible solutions

**Possible solution #1:**
You could restructure your tables like so:

```
--SQL DDL
CREATE TABLE Member(
  MemberID int PRIMARY KEY,
  Name varchar(25)
  Location varchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE User(
  MemberID int FOREIGN KEY,
  --Other User specific columns like login, expireDate etc.
)

CREATE TABLE Person(
 MemberID int FOREIGN KEY,
  --Other Person specific columns like Birthday etc.
)
```

With the new structure, your problem becomes simpler.  You can `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` (with cascading deletes setup) on the Member table using linq-to-sql.  Any new tables that are later added will just follow the same form of joining to the Member table with a foreign key, and no recompile will be necessary from any applications.  If this isn't a possible solution please explain why.

**Possible Solution #2**
Let's assume the above isn't possible due to legacy issues or permission issues.  Would it be possible setup views or stored procedures to mimic the above solution.  Something like the following stored procedure would allow you to select all members by name.  Inserts/Updates/Deletes may be more complicated if they are needed.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMemberByName @Name varchar(25) AS
BEGIN
        SELECT Name, Location FROM [User]
  UNION SELECT Name, Location FROM Person
  --Add more tables here when available
  WHERE NAME = @Name
END
```

Again, this is a solution that won't have you recompiling your code when a new table gets added.

**Possible Solution #3**
Finally, an in-code solution may be more of what you're looking for.  Again my questions about specifics are relevant.  When a new table gets added, are you going to be recompiling your L2S classes?  If yes, you may just be able to add the IMember interface to each of your table classes and then expose an `IQueryable<IMember>`/`IQueryable(Of IMember)`) property in the partial class of your derived datacontext that provides the `.Concat()` of all tables involved.  If no, you might have to query the database system tables to get all tables would have all the necessary IMember properties as columns, and select the union of them.  That seems like a lot of work, and I wouldn't envy you if you had to go that route.

Also, the possible requirement to write back updates/inserts/deletes to the appropriate table might have to loop through the possible tables to change the correct table.  Do the tables have an key that is uniq w.r.t. all member tables.  This is a great example where a GUID would shine because if you have a User with a name of Joe and a Person with a name of Joe, and they happen to have the same surrogate key of 1234, then once that entity is in a collection of IMember, how would you know what to update/insert/delete?

**Summary** I'm sorry if I sound like I'm being picky with asking for more detail, but it's really much easier for people to answer specific well defined questions.  Please either try to elaborate on your question or break it into smaller questions that can be answered a little more specifically.  Include relevant DDL to existing tables you know about to keep us from guessing, and relevant code snippets of stuff you've maybe already tried.  It'll pick up more eyes when people see a code block they can work with to help you improve it.